# Amazon Mechanical Turk submit button not working

Tags: mechanicalturk

The following is a snippet of a survey I would like to do on Amazon Mechanical Turk.

${offer_text1} : ${offer_text2}

I'm aware of the product
         I'm NOT aware of the product
    
    
    
    1
    2
    3

It shows up as two radio buttons to choose from and a drop down to choose a value from.
I used a survey template. However, when I actually tried publishing it, a "submit" button 
showed up in the survey (notice I have not inserted it here) and the golden "submit hit" button from amazon is greyed out. Am I missing something obvious?
Do I need to call GET/POST somewhere to post the results to amazon. Per the documentation, mturk should automatically get it for me. (I could be wrong here).

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The MTurk Requester User Interface automatically wraps everything in a set of `<form></form>` tags. Undoubtedly, you've put an additional set of such tags nested in the HIT as well, which then causes the HIT to fail (i.e., to gray-out the submit button and make it impossible to submit).